# Which app authorization dialog shows first? Push or Location

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications, core-location

I'm programming an app that uses core location for location tracking and push notifications to send remote push notifications. I'm wondering which authorization dialog shows first to the user and can the order be changed? (i.e. is it the push notifications authorization dialog asking the user to authorize the app for sending push notifications shows first or the location tracking authorization dialog.)

Thanks!

Comment: Its in a sequence in which you have written the code. 
If you called push notification first then it comes first.

Main thing is that. The Dialog will be overcome to the other dialog if its already there.

Answer (score 1):

Depends on the sequence in which you have written the code. So it won't be sure. The second one will always overlap the first one.